# TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined (nodejs)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i am following a project by udemy and i am having a TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of undefined

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();  
var mongo = require('mongodb');  
var monk = require('monk');  
var db = monk('localhost:27017/nodeblog');

/* GET home page. */  
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {  
var deb = req.db;  
var posts = deb.get('posts');  
posts.find({},{},function(err, posts){    
 res.render('index',{  
    "posts": posts  
});  
});  
});  

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: i mean... clearly `req.locals` is undefined, and therefore doesn't have a `db` property.

Comment: To add to the above: you're re-using the `db` var: once as the return value of `monk(...)`, and again inside your request handler as the return value of `req.locals.db`.

Comment: edited with db.get

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be the version of your express. Go to your json file, delete the express and **npm install express --save** . The currently version is  "express": "^4.15.2", if you are using 3.something could be it.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of the old version of express. Open package.json replace your old express version with "express": "^4.15.3" and then run npm install this will install the required package. Then run npm start to start the application.